# Create Fragment Dynamically Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How to create Fragment Dynamically and show data in fragment when Main.axml called in OnCreate method in android Xamarin.

Please Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create a `FrameLayout` for your fragment. For example:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create your application here
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    LinearLayout root = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.rootlayout);

    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
    frame.Id = 10001000;
    frame.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
    root.AddView(frame);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Add(frame.Id, fragment).Commit();
    }
}
```

Of course we need also create our custom `Fragment` for example like this:

```
public class MyFragment : Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Create your view and add your data here. Return this view.
        //For example:
        TextView tv = new EditText(this.Activity);
        tv.Text = "This is Fragment";
        return tv;
    }
}
```